# Python matching n-grams from a dictionary to a string of text

Tags: python, string, text, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 2 and 3 word phrases that I want to search in rss feeds for a match. I grab the rss feeds, process them and they end up as a string in a list entitled "documents". I want to check the dictionary below and if any of the phrases in the dictionary match part of a string of text I want to return the values for the key. I am not sure about the best way to approach this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
ngramList = {"cash outflows":-1, "pull out":-1,"winding down":-1,"most traded":-1,"steep gains":-1,"military strike":-1,
          "resumed operations":+1,"state aid":+1,"bail out":-1,"cut costs":-1,"alleged violations":-1,"under perform":-1,"more than expected":+1,
         "pay more taxes":-1,"not for sale":+1,"struck a deal":+1,"cash flow problems":-2}
```

Comment: What are some of the phrases you are trying to match?

Comment: The phrases I am trying to match are in the ngram list. Those are the phrases. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the numbers (-2, -1, +1) in that dictionary are weights so you need a count for each phrase in each document to make them useful.

So the pseudocode to do this would be :

1. Split up the document into a list of lines, then each line into a list of words.
2. Then loop through each word in a line, looping both forward and backwards in the line to generating various phrases.
3. As each phrase is generated keep a global dictionary, with the phrase and the count of occurrences.

---

Here is some code for the simple case of finding the count of each phrase in a document, which seems to be what you are trying to do :

```
text = """
I have a dictionary of 2 and 3 word phrases that I want to search in rss feeds for a match. 

I grab   the rss feeds, process them and they end up as a string IN a list entitled "documents". 
I want to check the dictionary below and if any of the phrases in the dictionary match part of a string of text I want to return the values for the key. 
I am not sure about the best way to approach this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
"""

ngrams = ["grab the rss", "approach this", "in"]

import re

counts = {}
for ngram in ngrams:
    words = ngram.rsplit()
    pattern = re.compile(r'%s' % "\s+".join(words),
        re.IGNORECASE)
    counts[ngram] = len(pattern.findall(text))

print counts
```

Output :

```
{'grab the rss': 1, 'approach this': 1, 'in': 5}
```

Comment: Emil, this is certainly one way to do it. I already have each rss feed preprocessed so I tokenize them into individual words. I am trying to avoid simply looping over each list item a bunch of times. I feel like there is a more elegant way which I think Krzysztof's method below is getting at but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I would merge all the strings into a regex and iterate over the matches it finds in the text. I'm not 100% sure, but I think the regex implementation in Python is smart enough to put all the words in a trie, which will give you good performance.

```
strings = [re.escape(s) for s in ngramList.iterkeys()]
regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(strings) + r')\b', re.IGNORECASE)
for text in documents:
    scores = []
    for m in regex.finditer(text):
        scores.append(ngramList[m.group(1)])
    # process the scores here, e.g. add their sum to some a global variable:
    score += sum(scores)
```

Comment: Thank you Krzysztof, this is exactly the type of thing I am looking for. Unfortunately it finds no matches and I built the dictionary from the actual rss feed text so I know they are there. I do not understand your method enough to fix it. Is there any reason why it would be returning no matches? this is what it is printing for the strings variable. see below. scores and score stay at 0

Comment: ['steep\\ gains', 'state\\ aid', 'pull\\ out', 'winding\\ down', 'alleged\\ violations', 'cash\\ outflows', 'bail\\ out', 'resumed\\ operations', 'military\\ strike', 'cash\\ flow\\ problems', 'under\\ perform', 'more\\ than\\ expected', 'not\\ for\\ sale', 'struck\\ a\\ deal', 'pay\\ more\\ taxes', 'most\\ traded', 'cut\\ costs']

Comment: @EnglishGrad, can you provide the contents of `documents`, or at least one of the texts inside of it (or a substring of one of these texts)?

Comment: I tried out my code and it seems to be working. Maybe `documents` is not actually a list of strings in your code? For example, it would not work if it were a dictionary, you would need to use `documents.iteritems()` in line 3 instead of `documents`.